# how can i know if an anchor link is clicked or not?

Tags: google-apps-script

**I want to know if an anchor link is clicked.**

I add anchor links dynamically and set ids with their name file but i dont know how amoutn the number of the cell "clicked" in my Spreadshett.

```
For ex: the id of file "test.pdf" --> test;
```

in spreadsheet:

```
ex:

ColumA  <namefile>: test.pdf
ColumB  <linkfile>: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1PiMj.....jramcs
ColumC  <cliked>: 1
```

I'm specting that if i clicked my anchor my function could know which anchor is cliked and amount " 1 "  in colum C in the ppropriate row.

```
var html = app.createAnchor(nf, hf).setId(nf);
```

I am trying to make something like:

```
var html = app.createAnchor(nf, hf).setId(nf).addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler("sumDoc").addCallbackElement(flexTableDoc));
```

***¿But how i know which anchor is cliked in the function sumDoc?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get that using client handlers and a textbox (this last one can be visible or not).

```
 var clickedItem = app.createTextBox().setName('clickedItem')
```

On each anchor you add a clickHandler like this

```
    var handler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(clickedItem).setText(Anchorname);
    anchor.addClickHandler(handler)
```

and in the server handler you will get the textBoxValue with

```
var clickedItem = e.parameter.clickedItem;
```

if you want a more accurate code you should provide the code you use to create the UI with the anchors

Comment: that was useful but i think it is more complicated using clientHanlders TY SO MUCH

Answer (score 1):

This is also possible and easy, format your anchor like you said.

```
var html = app.createAnchor(nf, hf).setId(nf).addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler("sumDoc").addCallbackElement(flexTableDoc));
```

Now your return function:

```
function sumDoc(e){
  //this will return the value of the ID of the element thats clicked so in this case its test.pdf
  var linkId = e.parameter.source;     
}
```

I hope this is useful

Comment: That was the perfect WAY!! ty for urge me! that was so easy e.parameter.source.